# Bootstrap Carousel first slide active using render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using render images to show my images. How can I set the first image to be active for Bootstrap Carousel to work? i.e. `<div class="item active">`

**rooms/show.html.erb**

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <%= render @images %>
</div>
```

**images/_image.html.erb**

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="item">
  <%= image_tag image.image.normal.url %>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <%= image.name %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <% @images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <%= render partial: "images/image", locals: {:index => index, :image => image} %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="item <%= 'active' if index == 0 %>">
  <%= image_tag image.image.normal.url %>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <%= image.name %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bruno updated it, that error was coming because *you have your partial inside images directory and your view is in rooms directory* so it was basically looking for a partial in rooms